# Role roles/bigquery.jobs.create is not supported for this resource (project)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

I'm using `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ...` command to add role: roles/bigquery.jobs.create (because this is necessity if you want to be able to run query in BigQuery GCP project).

I get an output:
`INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/bigquery.jobs.create is not supported for this resource.`

Problem here is I'm unable to set this through `bq` CLI as well, because it seems like permissions can be added on table/dataset level only. Anyone knows the possible solution (unix shell)?

Answer (score 2):

The IAM role you mentioned in the question does not exist. It is a permission rather than a role.

The list of roles and their descriptions are provided in the [BigQuery Predefined IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery)

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've mistakenly used permission and was supposed to use bigquery.user instead. I wish error message would be more helpful here. It was silly mistake, such role does not exist and they could mention that.